# How to remove dynamic span by clicking dynamic button using jquery if both have same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating these dynamic span with dynamic button i want to remove respective span when their button clicked

Example:if someone click on button with id 1 then span of id 1 gets removed using jquery 
(removed not hide)

```
<span id="1">text</span><button id="1">X</button>
<span id="2">text</span><button id="2">X</button>
<span id="3">text</span><button id="3">X</button>
<span id="4">text</span><button id="4">X</button>
<span id="5">text</span><button id="5">X</button>
```

I have created this but not working i am new to jquery.

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
        var id =  this.id;
        $( "span #"+id ).remove();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ID must be unique - only one for one page!

Comment: Use on() to do so. Refer to this link http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Are the buttons added dynamically as well?

Comment: @Alexander ***as a side note:*** Beware, you can have duplicate IDs if different document context, as using iframes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id`s must be unique, use `data` attribute instead to store the corresponding `id`s.

Furthermore, your selector `$( "span #" + id )` will select an element with some `id` that is a child of `span`. Remove the `span`, its unnecessary.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $("#" + id).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="1">text</span><button data-id="1">X</button>
<span id="2">text</span><button data-id="2">X</button>
<span id="3">text</span><button data-id="3">X</button>
<span id="4">text</span><button data-id="4">X</button>
<span id="5">text</span><button data-id="5">X</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your support my page is refreshing when clicked on button ! how to stop page getting refresh when button clicked

Comment: @royleewheels That's an other question, already answered thousand times before...  But clicking on BUTTON, shouldn't refresh the page unless it is inside a FORM. So set for each button `type="button"` (by default it is `submit`)

Comment: yeah its in form okay thanks for your advice will change it i am new to all this stuff

Comment: thanks chipChocolate.py and  A. Wolff as per your suggestions it worked like the way i want

Comment: By virtue of their uniqueness, ID selectors do not need *helpers*; so `"span#"` should just be `#`. By including `span` we're sort of saying that we can have `span#myid`, `div#myid`, `button#myid` in the same document ... not so.

Answer (score 0):

First set `class` attribute, remove `id`

Try this code :

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('span').remove();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id should be unique, beside that u could use something like this:

```
$('span[id="text'+id+'"]')
```

or

```
$('#text'+id)
```

and

```
<span id="text1">text</span><button id="button1">X</button>
```